# Autosaving EXE files in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, exe, autosave

Is there any setting in IE8 so that EXE files can be downloaded without a prompt?
I am attaching the prompt which i get when i try to download exe files.
I have to automate the process of downloading and as such it would be easy to do so if this prompt doesn't show up.[image]

Comment: Security risk, so unlikely possible.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go into internet options, through control panel or IE.
2. Set the "Launching Applications and Unsafe Files" option to enabled.

This will give you a retarded bar in IE that says your security settings are unsecure or something.

To get rid of it:

1. Start>Run>gpedit.msc>Enter
2. Under Administrative Templates>Windows Components>Internet Explorer set the "Turn Off the security settings check feature" to enabled.

If you don't have Internet Explorer under windows components:

1. right click Administrative Templates and click "Add/Remove Templates"
2. Click Add button
3. Navigate to "C:\WINDOWS\system32\GroupPolicy\ADM\"
4. Hold shift and highlight all the files that start with "inet"

search

http://ais-ss.usc.edu/helpdoc/main/browser/bris004b.html

Comment: Hi Feroz. Thank you for the response.
I tried what you have mentioned but i am still getting the warning.

Comment: have you restarted the browser

Comment: yes.
I have enabled Launchign Applications and unsafe files option  and restarted the browser